# XSLT do not match certain attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is it possible to match attributes that **do not** belong to a subset of attributes?  For example, I would like to match everything but @attr1 and @attr2.  Is there a way to write a template match statement similar to the following, or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
<xsl:template match="NOT(@attr1) and NOT(@attr2)">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@attr1|@attr2"/>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

The first template will catch the references to those you want to ignore, and simply *eat* them. The second will match the remaining attributes.

Comment: How about if at some other point in the script I would like to handle the attributes that were excluded. Do you know if that is still possible?  Basically I have hundreds of attributes that I need to match on, all requiring the same action, and only a very small subset require special handling.  So I would like to exclude the ones that need special handling, until I decide to handle them. I basically just need to print out the attribute names, and the assigned value.

Comment: I actually solved the problem using modes combined with your solution above.

    <xsl:template match="@attr1|@attr2" mode="common" />
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="common">
        ....
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@attr1|@attr2" mode="styles">
     ...
    </xsl:template>

Answer (score 3):

The original inquiry is possible. Use the following:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[local-name()!='attr1' and local-name()!='attr2']">
    ....
</xsl:template>
```

This is especially useful if you want to change an attribute or add it if missing withing a single copy operation. The other answer does not work in such situation. e.g.

```
  ...
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:attribute name="attr1">
        <xsl:value-of select="'foo'"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name()!='attr1']|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  ...
```