# Strip tags from XML using XSLT All Except Some (Negate condition)

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to remove all tags from my XML file except a finite number of tags, which i am aware of . How can i do that with XSLT.

I know i can use the following to strip div tags from my xml but i want to negate, like Strip all BUT Div.

```
  <xsl:template match = "div">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

More Snippet of the XSLT file:

```
  <xsl:template match="div"> <!-- switch the element name -->
    <xsl:element name="newdiv">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div"/>
  <xsl:template match="*"> 
     <xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
     </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1137101/1500313) already.
Use two templates.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <!-- Everything -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="something | somethingelse">
   <!-- what you want ignored -->
</xsl:template>
```

---

Fourth edit.

Input sample:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <div>content</div>
    </table>
    <div>content again</div>
</body>
```

XSLT transformation to do what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="div">
       <xsl:element name="div">
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates />
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This REMOVES ALL TAGS EXCEPT DIV. And KEEPS ALL TAG CONTENT. I just tried it.

Comment: That things works with Attributes but i am talking about elements/nodes. Can you please describe the solution a little further.

When i add these two template matches as suggested by you, they take off everything from the file.

Comment: And This one will also truncate everything related to those tags, i only want to strip the tags not the values.

Comment: MalSu - Thanks for helping out, but when i do these two templates it returns an empty xml with just the header so it removes everything, means all the tags and elements `<xsl:template match="div" /><xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
   </xsl:template>`

Comment: It seems you might want to improve the match. A sample of your document might help out.

Comment: thanks MalSu, I have update the code snippet above to show what i am doing, Actually i am first renaming one of the nodes and then i want to delete all other tags other than div from the file.

Comment: I tried out my steps of the code and its removing all tags except the one I specified, in this case "div".
I think you mentioned that it has to remove the tag, but leave the value?

Comment: Let me try again -

I WANT THE CONTENTS OF ALL THE TAGS REGARDLESS. but i want to remove all the tags EXCEPT <DIV> and <P>

This is the XSLT file i tried and it is not returning anything 
`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="div"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Xml file - 
`<title>this is title starting <div>div contents here</div> title comtents after div </title>`

Comment: Edited again, check it out. If you need to keep `<p>`, add a template for that as well.

Comment: I tried your options but this will i loose all the attributes of div ? Shouldn't i use copy-of instead of hard coding div ?

Comment: Some thing like this - `<xsl:template match="div">
  <xsl:element name="div">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`