# select all text out of nodes

Tags: xslt, select, text

I have the following xml and I need to extract the text that is outside the node "justified".

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><p><justificado><negrita>TEST.- </negrita>Hello people <negrita>it is</negrita><negrita>,</negrita> fa test ./justificado></p></body></html>
```

I have tried without success the following

```
<xsl:template match="not (*/negrita[preceding-sibling::*[1]self::negrita]])">test-123</xsl:template>
```

Comment: it seems like the tag "justificado" is not properly closed (./justificado)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137078/xslt-do-not-match-certain-attributes

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I do not want to lose what q is within bold tags.  Helpme!! please

Answer (score 1):

> I need to extract the text that is outside the node "justified".

The [default behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) of an XSLT stylesheet is to copy all text nodes - so in order to extract all text that is outside a specific element, you only need an empty template matching the text nodes that are **inside** the specified element:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::justificado]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input (after correcting the closing `</justificado>` tag!), the result is:

```
test
```