# XSL - Update or Create Attribute on Copy

Tags: xml, xslt, lxml

I have an XML document that I want to generate unique IDs for. Some nodes may already have the attribute in which case this is to be replaced. I want all nodes in the document to have the attribute.

An example document would be

```
<root>
<anode uid='123'/>
<anode/>
</root>
```

I am using the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="uid">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And am getting the following output. This is close to what I want, but how do I prevent the existing ID from being created as a text node?

```
<root uid="id515559">
<anode uid="id515560">123</anode>
<anode uid="id515562"/>
</root>
```

I have looked at [XSLT: How to change an attribute value during <xsl:copy>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615875/xslt-how-to-change-an-attribute-value-during-xslcopy) but I couldn't get this to create new attributes.

If it makes a difference I'm using lxml to process the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Built-in template rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) is being applied to the input `@uid` by the line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

The Default template for an attribute copies the text, behaving as though you had defined a template thus:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In order to prevent this being applied, either change your `apply-templates` select attribute so that it does not apply to attributes, or define a new blank template for any attribute, thus:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" />
```

You could even be more specific, using a similar template to ignore `uid` attributes only, thus:

```
<xsl:template match="@uid" />
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a template to match the existing **uid** attribute, and ignore it...

```
<xsl:template match="@uid" />
```

So, with this stylesheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:attribute name="uid">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@uid" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the output is as follows:

```
<root uid="IDAEQLT">
   <anode uid="IDA3XLT"></anode>
   <anode uid="IDA0XLT"></anode>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not really as extreme as adding a new match to override the `@uid`. You just need to remove the `select` from your `xsl:apply-templates`.

Your stylesheet with the `select` removed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="uid">
                <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output (`@uid` will vary):

```
<root uid="d0e1">
  <anode uid="d0e3"/>
  <anode uid="d0e5"/>
</root>
```