# XSL Transformation only for certain element based on attributes

Tags: xslt

I have a XML file for which transformation rules should be applied for certain elements only based on its attribute value and the rest should be retained as it is.

```
<bigdata>
<data>
    <Object class="QWE" Name="Country-1/State-1/QWE-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="RTY" Name="Country-1/State-1/RTY-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="UIO" Name="Country-1/State-1/UIO-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="PAS" Name="Country-1/State-1/PAS-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
</data>
```

The above xml should be converted to below xml snippet where only xml element **Object** for which **class** equals QWE should be changed to **POST**.
ie only first element in  must be changed based on its attribute.
Any advices on this would be gratefull

```
    <bigdata>
<data>
    <Object class="POST" Name="Country-1/State-1/POST-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="RTY" Name="Country-1/State-1/RTY-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="UIO" Name="Country-1/State-1/UIO-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
    <Object class="PAS" Name="Country-1/State-1/PAS-1">
        <p name="Map">20</p>
        <p name="Required">0</p>
        <p name="Combined">68</p>
        <p name="State">0</p>
    </Object>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object/@class[. = 'QWE' ]">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="'POST'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<bigdata>
        <data>
                <Object class="POST" Name="Country-1/State-1/QWE-1">
                        <p name="Map">20</p>
                        <p name="Required">0</p>
                        <p name="Combined">68</p>
                        <p name="State">0</p>
                </Object>
                <Object class="RTY" Name="Country-1/State-1/RTY-1">
                        <p name="Map">20</p>
                        <p name="Required">0</p>
                        <p name="Combined">68</p>
                        <p name="State">0</p>
                </Object>
                <Object class="UIO" Name="Country-1/State-1/UIO-1">
                        <p name="Map">20</p>
                        <p name="Required">0</p>
                        <p name="Combined">68</p>
                        <p name="State">0</p>
                </Object>
                <Object class="PAS" Name="Country-1/State-1/PAS-1">
                        <p name="Map">20</p>
                        <p name="Required">0</p>
                        <p name="Combined">68</p>
                        <p name="State">0</p>
                </Object>
        </data>
</bigdata>
```

Update if the class value should be start with a string (QWE) and only this part should be replaced. Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="Object/@class[starts-with(., 'QWE') ]">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="'POST'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'QWE')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What should be done if class="QWE-1" and i should be retaining the "-1" above. New value would be class="POST-1"

Answer (score 0):

Use following XSLT to transform above xml:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@class[parent::Object]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='QWE'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="'POST'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>
```

refer this for more info:

[XSLT: How to change an attribute value during <xsl:copy>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615875/xslt-how-to-change-an-attribute-value-during-xslcopy)

Comment: What should be done if class="QWE-1" and i should be retaining the "-1" above. New value would be class="POST-1"