# Change value of an XML attribute via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I have the following xml-file:

```
<Book description="for beginners" name="IT Book">
    <Available>yes</Available>
    <Info pages="500.</Info>
</Book>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<Book description="for pros" name="IT Book">
    <Available>yes</Available>
    <Info pages="500.</Info>
</Book>
```

I looked up how to modify xml-documents properly on the internet. I found out that first of all I should declare a template for just copying everything:

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I dont know how to write the template for the actual modification. Thanks for helping out a beginner.

EDIT: Here is my Stylesheet so far (as requested by uL1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@description='for beginners'">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:text>for pros</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: add another template that matches your target attribute `<xsl:template match="Book/@description"><xsl:attribute name="description">for pros</xsl:attribute></xsl:template>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is already answered in many other threads. Eg. [XSLT: How to change an attribute value during <xsl:copy>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615875/xslt-how-to-change-an-attribute-value-during-xslcopy)

In your case, you need a template, which matches on your attribute `description`, besides the identity-copy template.

```
<xsl:template match="@description"> <!-- @ matches on attributes, possible to restrict! -->
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">   <!-- creates a new attribute with the same name -->
    <xsl:text>for pros</xsl:text>   <!-- variable statement to get your desired value -->
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT 1** (further information cause of errors)

One complete, valid, runnable script would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@description[. = 'for beginners']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:text>for pros</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This seems to be the right direction. Unfortunately, i get an Error-message when trying to this in my xsl-stylesheet:
xsl:attribute: Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element.

Comment: `Cannot add attributes to an element if children have been already added to the element` occurs, when you create childnodes before you add the attribute to the context (e.g. current matched) node. changing the order might help. BUT there are several possibilities, eg. `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` before `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` will result in the error.

Comment: Isnt that what im allready doing at my copy template? :
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>

Comment: I can't reproduce any failure with not seeing the complete xslt, you are executing. please try it on your own, or post your complete stylesheet in addition to your question via [edit]. I will update my answer to that as far as i can.

Comment: I added the requested stylesheet.

Comment: Updated answer.